# How to install the packages that are downloaded during upgradation when the upgradation is interrupted?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, tty

I started upgrading my os from 14.04 to 16.04.1. During upgradation there is no progress when installing package "avahi" so I turned my laptop off. When I restarted it I couldn't boot, even if I can I get only terminal saying 16.04.1 tty and asking for my login credentials. Is there a way I can install the remaining packages and get complete GUI

Comment: Upgrade is a complex process. It's not just downloading some deb files and installing them. It seems you've messed up your upgradation. You need to start over again

Comment: If you can login try 'apt-get -f install' without further parameters. Then 'apt-get dist-upgrade' , mayby you have to do thi multiple times. You can also try to do ' cd /var/cache/apt/archives' (there are the downloaded pa

Comment: there are the downloaded packages. then do 'dpkg -i *.deb' , probably also multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot a live session of 16.04.1 and start an install as usual. At the point where the installer asks you what to do, where to install, choose **Something else** and make sure to select both swap and / to use but **do not select format**.

Result: Ubuntu 16.04.1 should be properly installed, correcting the errors from the broken upgrade.

Caveats: Although this method won't delete your user data and setting, it will remove user installed software -> mentioned in the warning message you will get (/var, /opt, /etc folders will be reset). Just reinstall all the needed software after getting back the desktop environment.

Comment: This might be the correct answer as Anwar suggested in a comment, but even so you have evaded the original question which was that Raviteja already downloaded very many packages before the upgrade was interrupted, is there anything that he can do to avoid downloading the same packages twice?

Comment: @karel -  It may be possible to do sudo apt install -f *if* the user can successfully login in TTY but it's even riskier than what I suggested above.

Comment: That makes sense to me, however it should also be taken into consideration that even if Raviteja restarts the upgrade from scratch, it may still fail at precisely the same place where it failed before unless he uninstalls avahi first.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I didn't suggest that but an installation over the (partial) upgrade without formating instead. The proposed method at least saves the user data and settings at /home.

Comment: The installation through terminal stops again at avahi-daemon, also sudo didn't work for installing packages because of some libc++ error